# Display characters in limit in .net

Tags: .net, model, substr, character-limit

I have a paragraph in `@Model.FileName` , I want to display first 20 characters. 
Any easy possible solution.
Here I means as `substr()` function work in PHP. I want same in .NET.

Comment: There is. You can find it in MSDN. There are even two functions for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in .net it is called `Substring` it will be there for any string

Comment: Should I use Substring(@Model.FileName, 20) ?

Comment: @Model.FileName.Substring(0,20);